# How to join data between RTK queries

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'd like to implement a kind of serialization system that compose an entity with another one from another RTK query.

For example, considering this entity :

```
interface MyEntity {
  //basic stuff
  id: number,
  // ...

  authorIds: number[],
  authors: User[],
}
```

My backend API responses aren't including the full users objects array, but only the array of ids.

```
{
  id: 1,
  authorIds: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

In my configuration, I have a queries for both MyEntity and Users (getMyEntities & getUsers), then doing the mapping everywhere in my React app whenever I never the full users objects.
But this is redundant, especially because User isn't the only object I'd like to compose in MyEntity.

Is there any way to transform MyEntity, like in transformResponse callback from RTK query, and access the getUsers cached result (or trigger the query if needed) to perform the transformation of MyEntity ? This would centralize this behavior in my state manager.

Else, could it be possible via middleware ?

Thanks for your suggestions,

Nothing from transformResponse arguments seems to provide an access to state or queries.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create another hook with useMemo to combine the result.

```
export function useGetCombinedQuery(params) {
  

  const entityQueryObj = useGetMyEntityQuery(params)

  const authorParams = {entity : entityQueryObj?.data.entity}
  
  //Second query only called after the first one succeed
  const authorQueryObj = useGetAuthorsQuery(entityQueryObj.isSuccess ? authorParams : skipToken)

  //Most important to ensure that React does not re-render
  const combinedData = useMemo(() => {

    // Check for result and combine the result from the two queryObj as required.
    
    return combinedData
  }, [entityQueryObj, authorQueryObj])

  
  return {
    ...authorQueryObj,
    data: combinedData
  }
}
```